# Flask: 404 not found, routes to /register.html instead of just /register, can't find the issue

Tags: python, flask

Beginner-ish flask user here, and i can't find where i went wrong.
i am routed to (/register.html) instead of (/register) so i know it's a blunder i made somewhere but everything looks alright to me, a pair of fresh eyes help me out.

Adding this because stackoverflow thinks my question is mostly code and wants me to add more details but i think my question is clear enough so please ignore this part.

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def register():
    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Get username and password from form
        username_submitted = request.form.get("username")
        password_submitted = request.form.get("pasword")

        # Query database for user
        user = users.query.filter_by(username=username_submitted).first()

        # Ensure a username was submitted 
        if not username_submitted or password_submitted:
            flash("must provide username and password", category="error")
            return redirect("/register")

        # Ensure the username doesn't exist 
        elif len(user) != 0:
            flash("username alredy exists", category="error")
            return redirect("/register")
        
        else:
            # Hash password
            hash = generate_password_hash(password_submitted)

            # Insert new user into database
            new_user = users(username=username_submitted, password=hash)

            try:
                db.session.add(new_user)
                db.session.commit()
                # Redirect user to homepage
                return redirect("/")
            except:
                return "error signing you up"

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or redirect) 
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

Here's my register form:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} 

{% block title %} 
Sign up 
{% endblock %} 

{% block main %}

<form action="/register" method="post">

  <div class="form-container">

    <div class="form">
      <div class="username">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" autofocus/>
      </div>

      <div class="password">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" class="btn" value="Sign up"/>
    
  </div>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem either, except you didn't mention whether the redirection from /redirect to /redirect.html happens on GET, POST, or both type of requests. Also, what does your "/" index function returns?

Comment: @Firelord the /register.html issue occurs on GET, my else statement in the register route, the POST request works as intended when i manually changed the url and tested it

Comment: Here's a simple test. Replace `return render_template("register.html")` with `return "Hello from register view"`. Now load the URL that points to /register and report the result.

Comment: is this the only route behaving this way? is this on a development server or production?

Comment: @Firelord i had to manually remove the .html but it works just fine beyond that, it returns whatever i ask it to return

Comment: @AudioBaton it is on a development server, and the login route also has the same issue

Comment: @jeddah Sorry, I cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem a few days ago
the issue was that the href on my anchor tags that link to the login and signup page looked like this:

```
<a href='login.html'>Login</a>
```

instead of:

```
<a href='login'>Login</a>
```